# DCount does not work. Pretty sure it has to do with the variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

My code stops running on the `DCount` line below.  In this `RC` is an `Integer` variable and previously set to 0.  RWPTitle is a string variable.  I think it has to do with how I have `RWPTitle` written.  Don't know if it is the quotation marks or what.  Not sure of syntax.

```
RC = DCount("PlanTitle", "rwpT", "PlanTile = " & RWPTitle)
```

Comment: Or is it because of the missing "t" in `PlanTile`?  (That **might** be the correct spelling, i.e. you may have a field called `PlanTitle` and another one called `PlanTile`, but I doubt it.)

Comment: And if `PlanTitle` (or `PlanTile`?) is a string field, it probably needs to be enclosed in apostrophes (`'`), i.e. `RC = DCount("PlanTitle", "rwpT", "PlanTitle = '" & RWPTitle & "'")`

Comment: Right on both counts.  I'm a little embarrassed about the misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is important to ensure you spell your field names correctly. ;)

Secondly, you usually will need to put quotation marks around string values.

```
RC = DCount("PlanTitle", "rwpT", "PlanTitle = '" & RWPTitle & "'")
```